# If loop for what type of Object is in a 2d array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, if-statement

I am currently working on a project, in which I have a maze. The maze is a two-dimensional array of Objects. I have several different objects (player, wall, path, minotaur) which will be in the array. I am writing a method that will display the map, and therefore it needs an if statement that can tell which type of object is in the specified position in the array. How do I do that?

the map array:

```
Object[][] map = new Object[20][20];
```

now in this if statement, I want to check if the specified position in the map array contains a certain type of object (e.x. a Player or Wall object). How do I do that?

```
if(map[i][j]/*checks if the objects is a Player object*/)
```

Comment: Have a look at the `instanceof` operator.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuilt operator `instanceof` which can do this.

```
if(map[i][j] instanceof Player)
```

Having said that, you should revisit your code and make it more typesafe , rather than having arbitrary objects in your array and type checking them.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Java 17 you can use the preview feature of switch expression with an instance of:

```
switch(map[i][j]){
case player -> // do player logic
case Wall -> // do wall logic}
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html

Comment: Switch expressions aren't a *preview feature* since Java 14. Pattern matching was finalized with Java 16.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko  did you look at the link? according to oracle pattern matching for switch expressions and statements is a preview feature in java 17

Comment: The statement in your answer is incorrect. Switch expressions are **not a preview future** since Java 14. Pattern matching for switch expressions is still a preview.

Answer (score -1):

you can use obj isInstaceOf() . like

```
if("Hello" instanceOf() String)
System.out.pringln("this is an string instance");
```

like 
```
if(map[0][0] instanceof() player){
//do the player logic
```

Comment: This is incorrect java syntax and does therefore not compile.

Comment: This is an example, if you show your bugged code i can give the exact syntax

Comment: @Sathiyaprakash Pay attention to what *@maloomeister* has pointed out. **instanceOf()** is incorrect.